# how to transpose column to row in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to rearrange my text file:

```
Record    :   Field1
              Field2
              Field3
Record    :   Field1 
Record    :   Field1
Record    :   Field1
              Field2
              Field3 
              Field4 
              Field5
```

How can I use awk or sed to rearrange it so that my output looks like this?

```
Field1, Field2, Field3
Field1
Field1
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
```

Comment: Are the fields fixed width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=', ' '{printf "%s%s", (/^Record/?ors:OFS), $NF; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
Field1, Field2, Field3
Field1
Field1
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
```

Comment: This seems to work, although how do you get rid of the , at the start of the list?                                                                                                                       , Field1, Field2, Field3

Comment: There's no comma at the start of the list so I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: You're right - I had another input file that had spaces in it, so basically I did this "/^       Record/" and it worked without adding a leading comma in front of the output.  Thanks for your help!!!  This group is on point...even more responsive than my own team members!

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NF==3{ if(s){ printf("%s\n",s) } s=$3; next }{ s=s", "$1 }END{ if(s) print s }' file
```

The output:

```
Field1, Field2, Field3
Field1
Field1
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
```

---

- `NF==3` - on encountering line with 3 fields (treating whitespace(s) as field separator)
- `if(s){ printf("%s\n",s)` - print previously processed/*transposed* column(s) as a single string
- `s=$3;` - capturing the 3rd field in line as a "*start of transposing phase*"
- `s=s","$1` - accumulating subordinate column values

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of sed:

```
sed -En "/^Record/!{s/^\s*/, /;H};/^Record\s*:\s*/{s///;x;s/\n//g;p};${s///;x;s/\n//g;p};" file
```

- if input is not start of record `/^Record/!`

  - replace leading whitespace by comma `{s/^\s*/, /;`
  - and add to history `H};`
- if input is start of record `/^Record\s*:\s*/`

  - trim the header `{s///;`
  - swap history `x;`
  - print one-line history `;s/\n//g;p};`
- same for last input line `${s///;x;s/\n//g;p};`

Answer (score 0):

Process the first record specially, print $3 directly.

For the following records, add an '\n' before print $3, or print $1 otherwise.

Please refer following straightforward solution.

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "%s",$3;next}
   {if($1=="Record"){printf"\n%s",$3} else {printf ",%s",$1}}
   END{printf "\n"}
'
```

output:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3
Field1
Field1
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5
```

Answer (score 0):

try one more awk with simple printf condition.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",/^Record/?$3:$1,/^Record/&&NR>1?RS:FS)} END{print ""}'  Input_file
```

Using simple printf which have 2 %s, to print 2 strings. So 1st string will be printed according to condition /^Record/ if a line starts from it then print 3rd field else print 1st field. Similarly with 2nd string and condition is if a line starts with /^record/ and line is NOT first line then print RS(Record separator, whose default value is new line) else print FS(field separator whose default value is space).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Record.*:\s*/{s///;:a;N;s/\s*\n\s\+/, /;ta;P;D}' file
```

Focus on lines beginning with `Record` followed by a number of characters, then a `:` and finally some spaces. Remove the front of this line using the match. Append the next line (if there is one) and replace any newline with spaces either side with a `,` and a space. Repeat if necessary, then print the line and repeat.